# OpenMP - Manage multiple calls to block with parallel for

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Let's say I have a program with a function called `run()`, this function will do a `for loop` and do some work inside it.

Since I want to take advantage of all my CPU cores, I use `OpenMP` with `#pragma omp parallel for` to parallelize it.

Now, the problem is that this `run()` function is called from several threads, and when there is a high number of threads calling `run()` at the same time, I have a huge performance penalty since there will be a lot of `OpenMP threads` from each `parallel for` pragma call.

Just to ilustrate, I have thread `A` and thread `B` and my CPU have 4 cores, thread `A` calls function `run()` which will create 4 `OpenMP` threads to run the `for loop`.

Now, at the same time, thread `B` also calls `run()`, this will generate more 4 `OpenMP` threads, resulting in a total of 8 `OpenMP` threads.

My question is if there is some way to balance this with `OpenMP`, in the example above, `OpenMP` could use half threads for `A` and half for `B`.
Another strategy would be to `OpenMP` create a thread queue, so it never uses more than 4 `OpenMP` threads.

Is something like that possible?

PS. Note that the 2 threads in my example is just to illustrate it, in my program it is not clear how much threads will be calling `run()` since the number of threads are created in run-time as needed.

PS 2. Note that whenever I'm talking about `OpenMP` created threads, I called it `OpenMP` thread, and when I'm talking about a thread created by other means (`std::thread` for example) I called it simply thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only OpenMP for parallelism, and you have [nested parallelism](http://%60omp_set_nested()%60) enabled you could use the `num_threads` argument to the `pragma omp parallel` to specify to use half of the threads:

```
int const currentNumThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
int const maxNumThreads = omp_get_max_num_threads();
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(maxNumThreads/currentNumThreads)
for ( ... ) {
   ...
}
```

Even if you are using mixed threading technologies (which seems to be your case), you could still accomplish the same by using different methods to set `currentNumThreads` and `maxNumThreads`.

A word of caution though. Using nested parallelism is generally inadvisable for OpenMP, as it makes code quite [fragile and rigid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_brittleness). Any change to your `run()` function needs to be aware of where it is called from, and any future calls to `run()` need to be aware of whats inside of it. Both in terms of performance and maintenance, trying to follow a [data parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_parallelism) approach for OpenMP usage is best. That is, perform a similar set of operations in each thread, but on a different chunk of data.

The exception to this, is if you are using OpenMP tasks, which you can spawn, and let the scheduler take care of it. Using task parallelism in a parallel for loop will tend to lead to poor performance due to a lack of [data locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) and high overhead if the tasks are small.

Comment: My problem is with mixed threading technologies as you said, but I don't think I manually changing `currentNumThreads` and `maxNumThreads` will work since it's not guaranteed that I will enter `run()` at the same time.
What I mean is that I can have a thread doing another thing that doesn't have nothing to do with `run()` and it will still count in th `num_threads()` calculation.